# Surjectivity of proper morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am trying to prove that, given a proper morphism of schemes $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$, if $Y$ and all fibers of $f$ are connected then $X$ is connected. It seems to me that it would help knowing if $f$ is surjective, so I am wondering if it follows from these hypotheses.

Comment: This depends on what saying "$S$ connected" means to you - if it includes the assumption that $S$ is nonempty, then you're fine because all the fibers are nonempty. If not, the inclusion of two closed points in to $\Bbb A^1_k$ is a proper map satisfying your hypotheses but not the desired conclusion.

Comment: My definition includes non-emptiness. Thank you! This was easier than I thought.